# Declare a new file UTI type from commandline in OSX

Tags: macos, file-association

My system understands a file UTI, `public.objective-c-plus-plus-source`, which conforms to `public.source-code`

I'd like to use a different extension for certain files that conform to this UTI. I'd like them to be opened with whatever application opens objective-c++ source.

My current thought on how to achieve this is to declare a new UTI, which conforms to objective-c++ source. I'm aware that I could create an application that exports the new type, but that wouldn't work well for me. Is it possible to register the new type with LaunchServices directly via the command line?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to download and install [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/). 
Go to System Preferences » Default Apps, then the MIME Types tab, or UTIs tab.

http://screencast.com/t/abG2w4m4qndT